# SQL query using string.format

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am developing a web application in c#,i want to write sql query by using string.format function as follows:

```
string sSql = string.Format("Select * From {0}", DbReference.TABLE_NAME_SEC_ROLES);
                if (roleCriteria._roleName != null && roleCriteria._isEnabled == true)
                    sSql += string.Format(" where {0}={1} and {2}={3} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName, DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL, roleCriteria._isEnabled);
                if (roleCriteria._roleName != null)
                    sSql += string.Format(" where {1} = {2} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName);
                if (roleCriteria._isEnabled == true)
                    sSql += string.Format("where {0}" + DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL + "'false'");
```

and it gives me exception as follows:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less
>   than the size of the argument list.

so, Please give me solution on this exception.

Comment: Instead of `String.Format` you should use [`Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: i must use string.format

Comment: If you do, you are asking for trouble. You shouldn't.

Comment: "i must use string.format" - either you don't understand what's being suggested and you do *not* need to use string.format, or this is homework and your teacher is a fool.

Answer (score 2):

This does not work and raises a [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
string.Format(" where {1} = {2} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName);
```

Instead you need to start with zero since `{2}` is equal to the length of the args array what is not allowed:

```
string.Format(" where {0} = {1} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName);
```

[`String.Format` Method (String, Object[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Edit**: Another bug found:

replace

```
string.Format("where {0}" + DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL + "'false'")
```

with

```
string.Format("where {0}", DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL + "'false'")
```

Here you have specified a format item but not added the argument.

> The number indicating an argument to format is less than zero, **or
>   greater than or equal to the length of the args array**.

---

**>>>** But i would recommend to use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead.

Comment: yes i already gone through this string.Format(" where {0} = {1} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName); but not working still there is same exception

Answer (score 0):

This is the line giving error

```
if (roleCriteria._roleName != null)                     
sSql += string.Format(" where {1} = {2} " + DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName);
```

Here you have used index 2 which does not exist. You should use 0 and 1.

Comment: There were at least *3* lines with errors which blow up `string.Format`, plus another few logical errors and a string concatenation error.

Answer (score 0):

There is *so* much wrong in such a short stretch of code. I think what you want is below, but I would *strongly* recommend that you switch to using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx). Treating everything as strings is an invitation to trouble:

```
string sSql = string.Format("Select * From {0}", DbReference.TABLE_NAME_SEC_ROLES);
if (roleCriteria._roleName != null && roleCriteria._isEnabled == true)
   sSql += string.Format(" where {0}={1} and {2}={3} " ,/* , not + */ DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName, DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL, roleCriteria._isEnabled); 
else if (roleCriteria._roleName != null) /* else added, otherwise this will fire if the above if did, and add a second WHERE clause */
   sSql += string.Format(" where {0} = {1} " ,/* , not + */ DbReference.ROLE_NAME_COL, roleCriteria._roleName); 
else if (roleCriteria._isEnabled == true) /* else added, otherwise this will fire if the first if did, and add another WHERE clause */
   sSql += string.Format(" where {0} = 'false'" , DbReference.IS_ENABLED_COL); /* , not +, and moved 'false' */
   /* Also, indented the `where`, since if only this if is true, it would mash the `where` onto the table name */
```

And we probably still need to insert some (`'`) quote characters, in places, since I'm guessing that some of these formatted in values will be strings. And *then* we have to deal with escaping quotes.